# Does "standard" Dijkstra's algorithm work with bi-directional edges and zero cost edges?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

I have been reading about Dijkstra's algorithm and I think I understand it. I followed the algorithm in pseudo-code from Wikipedia, and now I wonder:

1. If my graph is bi-directional and I add each edge to my graph *twice* (once "forwards", once "backwards"), will the "standard" Dijkstra's algorithm work?
2. Is it ok that some of my edges are zero cost? (the rest are all positive - none are negative)

And finally, what is a Dijkstra "heap" algorithm? Is it the same as Dijkstra's algorithm using a PriorityQueue?

Comment: I was wondering because I read a description of Dijkstra's referring to "non-negative costs" and I didnt know if this meant "non-zero" also.

Comment: By "path", I assume you mean "edge"? (A path is a sequence of edges.) "Non-negative" means exactly what it says, bearing in mind that zero is neither positive nor negative. Dijkstra works equally for directed and undirected graphs, so bidirectional edges are not a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both of these cases work. You can even have zero-cost loops.

Comment: Thanks. Any comment on what the "Dijkstra's heap" is ?

Comment: I haven't seen this name before. I'd _guess_ this was Dijkstra's algorithm using a heap as a priority queue (note that PQs can be implemented without using heaps, and that there are a few different related data structures called heaps, some of which are useful for Dijkstra's algorithm).